# How to move files that have a last access time 2 years ago

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need a script that moves all files I didn´t use 2 years ago in another directory.
Currently i got this:
`find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -atime -700 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;`

It moves all files I used in the past 700 days, but I want to move all files I didn´t used in the past 700 days.

Comment: Great. What [have you tried](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/475532/edit) so far,  NikSch? (We're not a script-writing service, but are very happy to help with specific problems that you've encountered trying to resolve your own issue.)

Comment: The problem is that i don´t know how to combine move and atime

Comment: Meanwhile i got this `find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -atime -700 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;` but that is not the way i want it :D Because it moves the files i used in that time but i want to move the files i didn´t used in that time

Comment: use `+700` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote,

> ```
> find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -atime -700 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
> ```
>
> It moves all files I used in the past 700 days, but I want to move all files I didn´t used in the past 700 days.

If you re-read the man page for `find` (`man find`) and search for the `-atime` directive you'll see that its values. A negative number means *less than (days)* and a positive number means *more than (days)* (you'll rarely find a use for zero).

You have specified `-atime -700`, which means *accessed "less than" 700 days ago*. You need `-atime +730`, which means *accessed "more than" 730 days ago*.

```
find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -atime +700 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Comment: and `find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -atime +730 -type f -exec mv -t /destination/directory/ {} +` to avoid calling `mv` for every file found.