# Is there a way to move my unused files and mirror their directories

Tags: linux, find, mv

I want to move my older files in another directory with a script like this

`find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -atime +700 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;`

That works well, but it´s not sorted like before.
So I am looking for a way to mirror the folders and sort the files in them like before.

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean, "_it's not sorted_"?

Comment: currently there are many folders with files in it and if I use that script all my unused files are in one folder. I hope you can understand that my english is not the best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move files that have a last access time 2 years ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475532/how-to-move-files-that-have-a-last-access-time-2-years-ago)

Comment: One option might be to have `find` construct the list of files to be moved, then call on `rsync` to do the 'heavy lifting' and make sure the directory structure is mirrored correctly.

Comment: @henrik *Not* a dupe - the answer to the linked question is the stepping-off point to this question. Related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: I retracted my close vote within minutes, when I realised there was a difference. Didn't think about deleting the auto generated comment though.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to rsync only the filers younger than 31 days from your source folder, you can combine rsync and find in this way:

```
rsync -Ravh $(find /path/to/folder/ -type f -mtime -31)  /path/to/destination/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now but try

```
find /sourcedirectory/./ -maxdepth 1 -mtime +700 -print0 |
    rsync -a --files-from=- --from0 --remove-source-files / /destination/directory/
```

---

Actually, since you've specified `-maxdepth 1` no subdirectories will be considered, so there is no need for anything other than the command you stated in your question:

> ```
> find /sourcedirectory -maxdepth 1 -atime +700 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
> ```

This makes it a duplicate of your [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475532/how-to-move-files-that-have-a-last-access-time-2-years-ago).

Comment: Is it maybe possible without rsync?